# PM2 process manager for Node across multiple cores

Tags: node.js, cluster-computing, pm2

I have a simple stateless Node app that I want to instantiate across a multi-core (multi-vCPU AWS instance) server, and I understand how PM2's cluster mode works to obviate the need for using the Cluster module in the app code.

I have a dual core AWS t2.medium EC2 instance, PM2 I believe is configured correctly and at startup it invokes two processes for the app with distinct PM2 IDs and PIDs.

PM2 is starting the app as follows:

```
pm2 start [app_name] -i max
```

PM2 lists the two processes with distinct PM2 IDs and distinct PIDs as expected.

However...

```
ps -U [username] -au
```

...suggests both processes are running on the same core.

Am I missing something? (Probably!)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

Processes aren't bound to cores, but rather assigned by the OS's scheduler. When your clustered program comes under load, the OS will use both cores to schedule your processes and, of course, all the other stuff it needs to run.